# Maclaurin Series, $\sqrt{7} = \sqrt{1 + 6}?$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am given the question:

True or False?
$$
\begin{align}
  \sqrt{7} &= \sqrt{1 + 6} \\
  &= 1 + \frac{1}{2}(6) + \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2!}6^2 + \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)}{3!}6^3 - \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{5}{2}\right)}{4!}6^4 + \cdots
\end{align}
$$

I know that the answer is false, but I am struggling to understand why. I was recently taught that $\left(1 + x\right)^r, \forall r \in \mathbb{R}$,$f(x) = \left(1+x\right)^r \Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{r}{n}x^n$.

Is it because $(1 + 6)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ means something else than $f(6) = (1 + x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: the binomial series for $(1+x)^{1/2}$ diverges for $|x|>1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{n}x^n$$
**diverges** when $n=6$, which can be seen using the ratio test.